# Running GNU Parallel while files exist

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, conditional-statements, gnu-parallel

I'm currently generating around 100 files from my script, I would like to iterate through
these files in batches of twenty, and execute them through another script, then remove the files when I am done (cleanup) I believe GNU Parallel can do this but I am not sure exactly how to do this?

```
# test if files exists and run
if [ "$(ls -A ${base_dir}/schedule)" ]; then

    while [ "$(ls -A ${base_dir}/schedule)" ]; do

        # current run of 20 files
        batch=`ls ${base_dir}/schedule | head -n 20`

        # parallel run on 4 processors
        parallel -j4 ./script.sh ${batch} ::: {1..20}

        # cleanup
        for file in "${batch}"; do
            rm "${base_dir}/schedule/${file}"
        done

    done
fi
```

expected output would be something like

```
# running first batch of twenty
 ./scipt.sh 1466-10389-data.nfo # after file has finished, rm 1466-10389-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-10709-data.nfo # etc
 ./scipt.sh 1466-11230-data.nfo # etc
 ./scipt.sh 1466-11739-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-11752-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-13074-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-14009-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-1402-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-14401-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-14535-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-1588-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-17012-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-17611-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-18688-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-19469-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-19503-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-21044-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-21819-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-22325-data.nfo
 ./scipt.sh 1466-23437-data.nfo

# wait till all are finished, OR queue up next file so  all times
# twenty files are running at until the directory is empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, and if the files in `schedule` are not continuously being created, the script could be replaced with those two lines (not tested)

```
ls -A ${base_dir}/schedule | xargs -n 1 -P 4 ./script.sh 
rm "${base_dir}/schedule/*"
```

Comment: This doesn't execute the files in parallel, it also echoes all the files into script.sh as a single parameter, them removes the entire directory. This isn't correct. =( I'll update my question so it makes more sense?

Comment: Ok misunderstood completely. Any reason then why you want to create batches of 20 rather than simply batches of 4 ?

Comment: Just realised I wrote `-p` (print) rather than `-P` (parallel). Still, it would indeed feed 20 files per script. Then rather than `-n 20` you would need `-n 1`. And the idea is to delete everything at the end. But this will not work by batches of 20.

Comment: That was one of the reasons that I recommended parallel, the reason of batches of 20 is server load, I have about 900 files to go through that operate on 20~ sites at a time, this was what we figured out our servers could handle sanely

Comment: I fail to understand why you need to work by batches of 20 files while at the same time limit yourself to maximum 4 concurrent processes.

Comment: I think im reading this wrong,I think I'm looking for 20 concurrent process until its done

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39942/discussion-between-damienfrancois-and-ehime)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want 20 scripts running constantly in parallel:

```
ls -A ${base_dir}/schedule | parallel -j20 ./script.sh {/}\; rm {}
```

Your while loop confuses me a bit: Is it needed because more files may be added while you run? If so you need to add that while loop:

```
while [ "$(ls -A ${base_dir}/schedule)" ]; do
  ls -A ${base_dir}/schedule | parallel -j20 ./script.sh {/}\; rm {}
done
```

Walk through the tutorial http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: While trying to do this, i'm getting no input while tring to execute my next file?

Comment: what is the output of 'parallel -V' and the above with --dry-run?

Comment: looks like the issue was that the directory from {/} wasn't correct?